# Why using "const" construction in JavaScript is a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, google-style-guide

In Google Style guide for JavaScript written ([prove link](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Constants#Constants)), that using a "const" construction is a bad practice, why?

Comment: As the link says, `const` isnt supported by IE.

Comment: This question seems now obsolete with ES6 and the link not working anymore

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because it is not standard (yet). It's a [JavaScript 1.5 keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), not ECMAScript. From the MDN documentation:

> The current implementation of `const` is a Mozilla-specific extension and is not part of ECMAScript 5. It is supported in Firefox & Chrome (V8) and partially supported in Opera 9+ and Safari. It is not supported in Internet Explorer 6-9, or in the preview of Internet Explorer 10. The `const` keyword currently declares the constant in the function scope (like variables declared with var).

Also if you read the section you linked to carefully, the last sentence is:

> As for the `const` keyword, Internet Explorer doesn't parse it, so don't use it.

Comment: These days const is supported in IE 11, but not IE 10